# Finding correlation between two groups in survey

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have a friend who asked me for help in statistics.  I study mathematics, but have never dealt with statistics in all of my years of study, so I don't want to give them the wrong information.  Either way, here's what is needed.

They have a group of $n$ participants in a study.  Some participants have property $A$, some have property $B$, and some have both.  What they want to know is the best way to measure if there is a correlation between those with property $A$ and those with property $B$.  The hypothesis is that if something is to have property $A$, they are more likely to have property $B$.  What is the best way to test this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Chi Squared test.

Create a $2$x$2$ table with colums (Not A, A) and rows (Not B, B)

You can see the rest at this link, the calculations should be fairly fast for a $2$ by $2$.

https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/chi-square-test.html

Comment: The gist of this test is that if there is no correlation, then the results should be perfectly spread out

Comment: Let's say that we have 50 adult women and 20 girls.

Comment: We suppose that they have the same interests (or not, we're here to find out)

Comment: We ask them if they like bicycling

Comment: 20 adults say yes and 30 say no

Comment: 8 kids say yes and 12 say no

Comment: in this case, it was the same proportion across women and children, so we can't infer any correlation between age and liking biking

Comment: our chi^2 statistic would be 0, and this would mean that there is no proven correlation

Comment: now, say 16 girls were to say and 4 say no. that is a hugely different proportion between women and girls, and the chi^2 statistic would be large this time

Comment: this would lead us to a low p value. the p value is the probability that there is no correlation. if there's a low chance that there's no correlation, there most likely is a correlation

Comment: usually, if this p value comes out to below 0.05, we cannot deny a possible correlation

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help!  This has made my friend's life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the correlation coefficient of the properties A and B. First find the covariance: E(AB)-E(A)E(B). Then find the Std. Dev.  of each. Use the formula $\frac {Cov(A,B)}{\sigma_A \sigma_B}$. To get correlation coefficient. It lies between -1 and 1. Closer to 1 means better correlation. Closer to zero implies no correlation. 
Note: E(A) is expected value of A

Comment: Thank you for your response.  What they want to know is if this corresponds to a well-known statistical test, or if there is a statistical test that best describes what you're recommending?